# Hitting time of Markov chain is minimal solution to quadratic equation

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a random walk on the natural numbers with probability $p$ of going from $i$ to $i+1$ and $q$ of going from $i$ to $i-1$. Let $T_0:=\inf\{n\geq 0 \,|\, X_n =0\}$ and $h_i:=\mathbb{P}_i(T_0<\infty)$, where the subscript $i$ means that the chain is started at $X_0=i$. Using the strong Markov property one easily gets that $h_1$ satisfies
$$
h_1=p h_1^2+q.
$$
Of course this generally gives two possible values for $h_1$. In my textbook it is claimed, without proof, that the correct one is always the minimal positive solution. I tried to prove this claim mimicking the proof in James Norris, Markov Chains, Theorem $1.3.2$ but had no success. Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: Can you double check your expression for $h_i$? Is it supposed to be the probability that the random walk starting at $i$ reaches the origin?

Comment: Let me know if my answer is deficient, but can you elaborate on why you get that quadratic for $h_1$? I explicitly solve the difference equation $h_n = ph_{n+1} + qh_{n-1}, h_0 = 1$ to get a solution, but getting the equation that you wrote seems to use something else?

Comment: The derivation is at page 16 of these notes https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~rrw1/markov/M.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiF0oaLv8-AAxX6XvEDHaYgCmgQFnoECAwQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2m_L9KTi5iAHxSSGftv84M

Answer (score 1):

Let's solve for $h_1$, using the relation that $p = 1-q$. The quadratic formula dictates that if $h_1$ is our solution,
$$h_1 = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1-4pq}}{2p}.$$
Let's look under the discriminant.
$$1-4pq = 1-4p(1-p) = 1-4p+4p^2 = (2p -1)^2.$$
If $p \geq 1/2$, our solutions are
$$h_1 = \frac{1 \pm (2p-1)}{2p} = \{1, q/p\}.$$
We can eliminate the solution $h_1 = 1$ on the grounds that there is a nonzero probability our chain ends up at $\infty.$

Comment: Thank you! Can you elaborate on why we eliminate the $h_1=1$ solution? I mean, is there some general "principle" (theorem) that tells us that we must always take the minimal positive solution or is it something that must be checked by hand case by case?

Comment: In general, when you set up these equations, there should only be one solution. In this case, if $p > 1/2$, we can show that the random walk is transient (diverges to $+\infty$ by the strong law of large numbers. This tells us that $h_n \to 0.$ The general solution for the recurrence equation $h_n = ph_{n+1} + qh_{n-1}$ is $c_1 \phi^n + (1-c_1)\cdot 1$ for some $0 \leq c_1 \leq 1,\phi = q/p.$ (This is related to the "characteristic equation" in your notes.) As $h_n \to 0$, $c_1 = 1$. Taking the minimal positive solution corresponds to using other information, it would seem.

Comment: I understand what you say and it works fine. The point is that the notes seem to suggest that there is a general principle about taking the minimal positive solution and that is shouldn't use additional information. I am expecting a result along the lines of Theorem 2.4 at page 11 of the notes (which is the same as Theorem 1.3.2 in the book of Norris that I mentioned in the body of the question).

Comment: The notes you linked prove your result for you (theorem 3.4, page 11.) We are looking for the vector of hitting probabilities, which must be the minimum nonnegative solution of $h_n = ph_{n+1} + qh_{n-1}$. We then derived the two values that $h_1$ could be and took the smallest one according to the theorem. I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding your question

Comment: The point is how do we know that if we take the minimal $h_1$ that solves $h_1=ph_1^2+q$ and construct the sequence $h_0=1, h_1, h_2,h_3,...$ according to the recursive relation $h_n=ph_{n+1}+qh_{n-1}$, then $h_i\geq 0$ for all indices $i$? If this is the case, then we can apply the theorem at page $11$ of the notes and conclude. But proving the non-negativity of the $h_i$ is exactly what I don't know how to do, since in general it is possible that $h_0,h_1\geq 0$ but $h_i<0$ for some $i$, in which case the theorem would not apply.

Comment: (continued) Of course one can check $h_i\geq 0$ by hand in this specific case, but as I said I would like to understand if there is a general principle behind the fact that in several scenarios apparently all different from one another the right solution is always the minimal one.

Comment: I don't know of a way to generally conclude that the $h_i$ you get are nonnegative without explicitly solving for the recurrence relation you get, (sidestepping the whole $h_1 = ph_1^2 + q$ equation.) When we derived $h_2 = h_1\cdot h_1$, we used the fact that our chain doesn't have jumps above length 1 and so got a quadratic equation, but in general there is no guarantee we can simplify like this. I'm also not sure this holds in general because we could have a recurrence relation that depends on, say, all of the $h_n$ (i.e., $p(x,y) > 0$ for all states $x,y$.) Sorry I can't help.